# gatsby.js - advanced starter - Implement 2 url prefixes (2 different sections of site)?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

It looks as though if you put your jsx files in the 'pages' folder of most gatsby starters, the urls follow the directory structure out of the box, so you can implement whatever urls you need (http://blah.com/**foo**/post1, http://blah.com/**bar**/post2) just by nesting folders in the source tree (`pages/foo/post.jsx`, `pages/bar/post2.jsx`).

## The issue

I used the **gatsby advanced starter** (https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter). It puts all content files not in `pages/`, but in a top-level `content/` folder and I can't figure out the wiring to replicate foo/xxx, bar/xxx urls even after creating `content/foo/post1.md`, `content/bar/post2.md` folders.

It *does* have a siteconfig.js that sets a single path prefix, but I want **two** different prefixes for the 2 different sections of the site, so I just set it to "/" for now (builds seem to ignore whatever value I set for this config param anyway, so... shrug).

## What I tried

- I tried adding `path` to the frontmatter of the .md files and set it to the parent foldername. This was completely ignored (in any case I don't think that's what I want... I'd like to keep the generated slug as part of the url).
- Separated use of `gatsby-source-filesystem` one for each subfolder hoping it would change graphql graph to recognize 2 separate data sources but it made no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It looks as though if you put your jsx files in the 'pages' folder of most gatsby starters, the urls follow the directory structure out of the box [...]

That's not specific to Gatsby starters, that's Gatsby's default behaviour. Every js/jsx file in `src/pages` will be a page.

> but in a top-level `content/` folder

It still has the `src/pages` folder for normal pages. But the `content` folder holds the files will be transformed with the `src/templates` in `gatsby-node.js` to pages. Or in other words: The contents of the `content` folder get programmatically created with the defined template in `gatsby-node.js` (and the template lies in `src/templates`).

---

The path/url get's defined in the `createPage` function here: [gatsby-nodeL144](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L144). This line is referencing the `edge.node.fields.slug` which gets queried in the GraphQL above [here](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L116). The field gets added in the [onCreateNode](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L50-L87) function. More specificially the `slug` field in the [onCreateNodeField](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L84) function. There you see that it gets passed a `slug` that gets defined above.

---

Create two folders in your `src/content` folder, e.g. `blog` and `projects`. Make sure that you have both of them defined in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    name: 'blog',
    path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    name: 'projects',
    path: `${__dirname}/content/projects`,
  },
},
```

In your `gatsby-node.js` add after the [fileNode](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L54) definition the line:

```
const pathPrefix = fileNode.sourceInstanceName
```

The `sourceInstanceName` is that what we defined as the `name` in `gatsby-config` entries.

Then you can alter the [line](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/d6b76a185f7e1095a2181d5f203b4f87f0f576cd/gatsby-node.js#L84) to:

```
createNodeField({ node, name: "slug", value: `/${pathPrefix}${slug}` });
createNodeField({ node, name: 'sourceInstanceName', value: pathPrefix });
```

The second line is helpful if you then want to query only for one of the two folders, e.g.:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fields: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "blog } } }
    ) {
        edges {
          node {
            ... etc
          }
        }
      }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for patiently explaining this - I understand gatsby a lot better now and Thank you for this awesome starter!!

Comment: How would you edit this to generate the pages at "/blog" instead of at "/"? I managed to move them to "/blog" by editing [this line](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/c56501331fc5049e374eb9757b6c491a01113f9a/gatsby-node.js#L104), adding "blog" after the "/" but this breaks the navigation when trying to navigate to previous blog pages (clicking "previous" or "1")